# T-SQL Query - Return One Result, or return 0 (SQL 2008R2)

Tags: sql, t-sql, view, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm quite the novice when it comes to T-SQL, and I can't figure out this query.

I am trying to compare an Item's value to it's ledger Value to check for any anomalies, because occasionally they go out of sync.

I need the query to, for all current stock, subtract the Item Ledger's 'Amount' field from the Item's 'Item Value' field. There are several Item Ledger Entries, it must subtract the amount from the ledger entry that is Open. If there is no Open Ledger Entry, subtract zero instead.

I've butchered together a query in the query designer, apologies for the sloppiness:

```
SELECT dbo.[Company$ItemTable].[Item No_],
       dbo.[Company$ItemTable].[Current Stock],
       dbo.[Company$ItemTable].[Item Value],
       dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].[Open],
       dbo.[Company$ItemTable].[Item Value] - SUM(CASE
                                                    WHEN dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].[Open] = 1 THEN dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].Amount
                                                    ELSE 0
                                                  END) AS Diff,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].[Open] = 1 THEN dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].Amount
             ELSE 0
           END)                                        AS AmountILE,
       dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry No_]
FROM   dbo.[Company$ItemTable]
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry]
         ON dbo.[Company$ItemTable].[Item No_] = dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].[Lot No_]
GROUP  BY dbo.[Company$ItemTable].[Item No_],
          dbo.[Company$ItemTable].[Current Stock],
          dbo.[Company$ItemTable].[Item Value],
          dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].[Open],
          dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].[Entry No_]
HAVING ( dbo.[Company$ItemTable].[Current Stock] = 1 )
       AND ( dbo.[Company$ItemTable].[Item Value] - SUM(CASE
                                                          WHEN dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].[Open] = 1 THEN dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].Amount
                                                          ELSE 0
                                                        END) > 1 )
       AND ( dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry].[Open] = 1 )
```

Does this make sense? Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to ask a specific question.  Right now, it's not clear what your question is nor what a correct answer to it would look like.

Comment: Sorry,

I want to return the value of ([ItemTable].[Item Value] - [Item Ledger Entry].[Amount]) as 'Diff'. If there is no Item Ledger Entry within the filters (IE - No 'Open' Entries), return 0.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Doesn't your query above already do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure is unclear. I can guess what you mean.
Is dbo.[Company$ItemTable].[Item No_] unique in table? 
Is dbo.[Company$ItemTable] relates to dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry] as one-to-many?

If yes then

```
SELECT 
   items.[Item No_],
   items.[Current Stock],
   items.[Item Value],
   items.[Item Value] - ISNULL( le.OpenAmount, 0) AS Diff,
   ISNULL( le.OpenAmount, 0) AS AmountILE
FROM   dbo.[Company$ItemTable] items
OUTER APPPLY
(
    SELECT SUM(e.Amount)
    FROM dbo.[Company$Item Ledger Entry] e
    WHERE items.[Item No_] = e.[Lot No_]
    AND e.[Open] = 1
) le(OpenAmount)
WHERE items.[Current Stock] = 1
```